# Like Operator is not working with Dynamic Variable in SOQL Query

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, dynamic-soql, dynamic-apex

Here I'm trying to perform LIKE operation in SOQL when I'm passing a variable dynamically the Query is not returning the results?

```
List<string> companies=new list<string>();
List<Account> leadAccountIds=[Select Id, OwnerId, Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE : '%' + companies + '%'];
```

I tried Like below ways

```
LIKE  '%+ companies +%'
LIKE: '%companies %'
LIKE:('%'+companies+'%')
```

Please help me?

Thanks In Advance!...

Comment: `companies` is `List<string>`. Does it contain only one string or multiple strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have multiple entries, you need to prepare a String like this way

```
Select Id, OwnerId, Name FROM Account 
WHERE Name LIKE '%ABC%' 
OR Name LIKE '%BCA%' 
OR Name LIKE '%XYZ%'
```

For each individual item in the list, it should be followed by `LIKE` operator as above.

> Recommended approach as follows:

```
List<string> companies=new list<string>(); 
List<String> soqlLikeStr = new List<String>();

//loop through each item in companies list
for(String str:companies)
{
    soqlLikeStr.add('%'+str+'%');
}

List<Account> leadAccountIds=[Select Id, OwnerId, Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE :soqlLikeStr];
System.debug('leadAccountIds=' + leadAccountIds);
```

Comment: Hi Santanu Boral,

It's true, but how to pass dynamically(Variable)

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

In **List companies=new list()** what it will hold List of String OR only One String? 
if it holds only one String then Please replace the List with String Like below: -

```
String companies;
String likeFilter = '\'%'+companies+'%\'';
List<Account> leadAccountIds = new List<Account>();
String Query = 'Select Id, OwnerId, Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE ' + likeFilter;
leadAccountIds = Database.Query(Query);
```

For List of Records, You need to do Some manipulations on the List and then use Include Operator

Answer (score 0):

You can do something Like

```
string tempInput = '%' + companies + '%';
[Select Id, OwnerId, Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE : tempInput ];
```

or if you are making dynamic SOQL

```
String val='\'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(inVal.trim()) + '%\'';
```

and then use this in the query:

```
' LIKE ' + val;
```

Comment: Hi Tushar Sharma,

I tried the above way, it's not worked(not getting results).

When I'm tring query in developer console its working, Why not here?

Comment: @VINOD if it is working in developer console that means the query is correct. Can you confirm if you have data which match filter criteria and user have proper permission?